# paste operation fail due to many cell formats

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have an excel file with many rows, and am trying to copy severl columns from this file to another file. However, the paste operation gives the following error message. I am not clear what does that mean and how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shown below is a quote from microsoft website as it will depend on your excel version

> In Microsoft Excel 2003, when you format a cell or a range of cells, you may receive the following error message:
> Too many different cell formats.
> Excel encountered an error and had to remove some formatting to avoid corrupting the workbook.
>
> In Microsoft Excel 2013, 2010, or 2007, files may produce the following error message:Excel found unreadable content in the file

One solution could be if you only need the values is to copy and paste special as values into the same workbook (diff sheet) and then try to copy into the new workbook. or do this same process but paste without the formatting using paste special.

I would be able to answer more if i new what kind of data was involved or the kind of formatting but give that a go and see if it helps